# Disable a button if (length < x)

Tags: javascript, html, button

good evening.
I'm a beginner with JavaScript and I'm trying to recreate a specific webpage. There, exists a button that, if the login form doesn't have at least 11 elements on user and 8 on password, the button is disabled.
How can I do this with HTML and JS?

```js
function blockButtonByUser() {
  var cpfleng = document.getElementById('.iptuser').length
  console.log(cpfleng)
  var btnsubmit = document.getElementById('.btnsubmit')
  if (cpfleng < 11) {
    btnsubmit.disabled = true;
  } else {
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
  }
}

function blockButtonByPassword() {
  var passwordlength = document.getElementById('.iptpassword').length
  console.log(cpfleng)
  var btnsubmit = document.getElementById('.btnsubmit')
  if (passwordlength < 8) {
    btnsubmit.disabled = true;
  } else {
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<header><img src="assets/white.svg" alt="logo nubank" height="80px"></header>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Faça seu login</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="user">
      <label for="cpf" class='lbluser'>CPF</label>
      <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class='iptuser'>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
      <label for="password" class='lblpassword'>Senha</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class='iptpassword'>
      <div class="underline"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="CONTINUAR" class='btnsubmit'>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="esqueci">
      <a href="links/forgot.html">Esqueci minha senha ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="naocliente">
      <a href="#">Ainda não sou cliente ></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why aren't you using a form tag? And you specify the elements in `getElementById` as classes. Needed without `.`.

Comment: Cuz I don't want to create the backend or submit this form anywhere, just want to recreate the layout. Maybe if I use the form tag, could I disable it?

Comment: You can also disable the button without the form tag.

Comment: It looks like you already have logic that is trying to do this. Which part of it isn't working?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe something on JS Code, since I started studying it this week hahah.

Comment: As @s.kuznetsov said, one of your problems is that you're using `.getElementBy*Id*`, but not using their `id`.  You're mixing the class name and id.  The `id`s are `cpf` and `password` not `iptuser` and `iptpassword`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it (use the ID from the inputs and buttons and changed it on js), but stills not working. I even stop using the CSS to better seeing if the button is disabled, but the button continues able.

Comment: You'll probably want to learn about [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), in this case the [minlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength) attribute which you could set as `minlength="11"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something like that using an `eventListener`:

```js
var cpfOkay = false
var passwordOkay = false;
var btnsubmit = document.getElementsByClassName('btnsubmit')[0];

document.getElementById('cpf').addEventListener('input', function(){

  btnsubmit = document.getElementsByClassName('btnsubmit')[0];
      cpfOkay = false;
    if (event.target.value.length >= 11) {
        cpfOkay = true;
    }
    checkBoth();
})

document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('input', function(){

  btnsubmit = document.getElementsByClassName('btnsubmit')[0];
    passwordOkay = false;

    if (event.target.value.length >= 8) {
        passwordOkay = true;
    }

    checkBoth();
})

function checkBoth() {
      btnsubmit.disabled = true;
      btnsubmit.style.opacity = 0.5;

  if (cpfOkay && passwordOkay) { 
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
        btnsubmit.style.opacity = 1;
  } 
}
```

```html
<header><img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="logo nubank" height="80px"></header>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Faça seu login</h2>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="user">
            <label for="cpf" class='lbluser'>CPF</label>
            <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class='iptuser'>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="password">
            <label for="password" class='lblpassword'>Senha</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class='iptpassword'>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="CONTINUAR" class='btnsubmit' disabled style="opacity:0.5">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="esqueci">
            <a href="links/forgot.html">Esqueci minha senha ></a>
        </div>
        <div class="naocliente">
            <a href="#">Ainda não sou cliente ></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add event listeners for `input` event for both the `user` and `password`, and based on requirements you can enable or disable the button. You can refactor your code like this:

```js
var cpf = document.getElementById('cpf')
var password = document.getElementById('password')
var btnsubmit = document.getElementById('btnsubmit')

cpf.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    if(cpf.value.length < 11 || password.value.length < 8){
    btnsubmit.disabled = true;
  } else {
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
  }
});

password.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    if(cpf.value.length < 11 || password.value.length < 8){
    btnsubmit.disabled = true;
  } else {
    btnsubmit.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<header><img src="assets/white.svg" alt="logo nubank" height="80px"></header>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Faça seu login</h2>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="user">
            <label for="cpf" class='lbluser'>CPF</label>
            <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class='iptuser'>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="password">
            <label for="password" class='lblpassword'>Senha</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class='iptpassword'>
            <div class="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="CONTINUAR" class='btnsubmit' id='btnsubmit' disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="esqueci">
            <a href="links/forgot.html">Esqueci minha senha ></a>
        </div>
        <div class="naocliente">
            <a href="#">Ainda não sou cliente ></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues. One was getElementById on classes. One was no event handler. Lastly, you were trying to get the length on the element, but not the length of the value.

This should work:

```
document.querySelector('.btnsubmit').addEventListener('click', e =>{
    blockButtonByUser();
    blockButtonByPassword()
})

function blockButtonByUser(){
    var cpfleng = document.querySelector('.iptuser').value.length
    console.log(cpfleng)
    var btnsubmit = document.querySelector('.btnsubmit')
    if (cpfleng < 11) {
        btnsubmit.disabled = true;
    } else{
        btnsubmit.disabled = false;
    }
}

function blockButtonByPassword(){
    var passwordlength = document.querySelector('.iptpassword').value.length
    console.log(passwordlength)
    var btnsubmit = document.querySelector('.btnsubmit')
    if (passwordlength < 8) {
        btnsubmit.disabled = true;
    } else{
        btnsubmit.disabled = false;
    }
}
```